# No sound through hdmi - ati radeon HD 3470, 12.04 - tried everything

Tags: 12.04, sound, ati, hdmi

I have Asus Laptop model F6V with Ati Radeon HD 3470 graphics and Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (precise pargolin). I have set the the output to HDMI but get no sound. Speakers and headset are ok.

I tried several things but nothing: check with alsamixer if HDMI is unmuted, added

```
radeon.audio=1
```

to grub, added

```
options snd-hda-intel xxx model=xxx
```

with various options to `/etc/modeprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Reinstall pulseaudio, install pavucontrol, upgrade kernel to 3.13.0-46. HDMI audio was working with previous Ubuntu version (I think it was 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot).

```
aplay -l  
card 0 : Intel [ HDA Intel ] , device 0 : ALC662 rev1 Analog [ ALC662 rev1 Analog ]  
card 0 : Intel [ HDA Intel ] , device 1 : ALC662 rev1 Digital [ ALC662 rev1 Digital]  
card 1 : HDMI [ HDA ATI HDMI ] , device 3 : HDMI 0 [ HDMI 0 ] 

aplay -D plughw:1,3 ~/aa.wav  
Now Playing WAVE 'aa.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Frequency 44100 Hz, Mono
```

I did't get any errors but no sound through HDMI

I tried also log on into guest session:

```
aplay -D plughw:1,3 ~/aa.wav  
Now Playing WAVE '/tmp/guest-8bTvdr/aa.wav : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Frequency 44100 Hz, Mono
```

Same result, no errors but no sound through HDMI

```
cat /proc/asound/modules  
 0 snd_hda_intel  
 1 snd_hda_intel
```

I don't know if it is relevant but initially HDMI was not showed in the pulseaudio audio setting selection list.
I had to edit `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/hdmi-output-0.conf`

```
  [Jack HDMI/DP,pcm=3]  
required -any = ignore
```

to be able to see audio setting selection list.

Hope to solve the problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're currently running? What the previous version was?  Does it work under the guest session?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: @Fabby Thanks very much!! I have added the information